# How should I refine "XX is widely used internally"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to express that a mechanism is used both internally and widely.

So I tried

> This mechanism is widely used internally

but I'm using two adverbs that surrounds a verb, looks inappropriate.

Any suggestion? Hopefully it doesn't break into two sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is technically correct, though it seems that you consider its wording to be awkward. Depending on the context, you may be able to move "internally" to the beginning of the sentence, as in:

> Internally, this mechanism is widely used.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to describe the extent of use (widely) within a particular domain (internally), your sentence is fine. If you're not intending to limit the extent of use to the domain, then perhaps

> This mechanism is used internally and widely.